# how do i replace in javascript user[0].firstName with user.firstName

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I want to access the information from my object like this

```
user.firstName
```

but I'm currently doing it like this

```
user[0].firstName
```

I'm using angular js

this is the object structure

```
0: ObjectAccessKey: "example.com"BirthDate: "1969-12-31"CellPhone: "(888) 888-8888"City: "Holtwood"ClosedRegisterAt: nullCompanyId: "1"CreatedAt: "2015-05-31 20:31:00"EditedAt: "2015-05-31 21:32:22"EmergencyContactName: "hhhehee"EmergencyContactPhone: "(717) 444 4344"Employee: "Ben Eshleden"EmployeeId: "8"FirstName: "Ben"LastName: "Eshleden"MailingAddress: "1131 holtwood rd"OpenedRegisterAt: nullPassword: "candoa21"State: "AK"ZipCode: "17532"
```

Comment: Please post your object structure, [0] is how to access an index in an array.

Comment: how and when are you trying to access it. that will help give suggestions of what method to use to access the user.

Comment: `user = user[0];` but the question, "Why?" still stands.

Comment: maybe `user = user[0];` then `user.firstName` but you have to show the object structure for more accurate information

Comment: first of all, i'd recommend to rename `user` to `users` as it seems to be an array of users. then you can do `var user = users[0]` and then you can use your `user.firstName` to access user's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$.each(user, function (i, eachuser) {
 name = eachuser.firstname;
}
```